# How to verify that a Kubernetes deployment update has been successful?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I have a simple Kubernetes deployment. It consists of a single, unreplicated container. There is no service exposing the container. The container has a health check which checks that it is correctly configured and can communicate with its external dependencies. I update the deployment using `kubectl apply`.

After updating the deployment, I would like to check that the new version has been rolled out completely and is passing its health check. I can't work out how to configure my deployment to achieve that.

I have tried various combinations of liveness and readiness probes, deployment strategies and ready/progress deployment properties. I've tried inspecting the status of the deployment, its pods and the rollout command. All to no avail.

I get the impression that I should be looking at deployment conditions to understand the status, but I can't find clear documentation of what those conditions are or how to bring them into being.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have not mentioned your deployment strategy. But one generic problem I have seen with k8s deployments is that if the application fails to boot up, it will be restarted infinitely. So you might have to `kubectl delete deploy/******` explicitly after detecting the deployment failed status. (There is also `failureThreshold` for probes, but I didn't try yet).

Case **Recreate**:

You can use the combination of `progressDeadlineSeconds` and `readinessProbe`. Let's say your application needs 60 seconds to boot-up/spin-up. You need to configure `progressDeadlineSeconds` a bit more than 60 seconds just be in the safer side. Now, after running your `kubectl apply -f my-deploy.yaml`, run the `kubectl rollout status deploy/my-deployment` command. For me it looks like this:

```
12:03:37 kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml
12:03:38 deployment "my-deployment" configured
12:04:18 kubectl rollout status deploy/my-deployment
12:04:18 Waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available (minimum required: 1)...
12:04:44 deployment "my-deployment" successfully rolled out
```

Once you execute the `rollout` command, kubectl will keep waiting till it has some answer. Also it returns with a proper exit code `echo $?` - you can check this programmatically and delete the deployment.

Case **rollingUpdate**:

If you have multiple replicas, then the above mentioned trick should work.
If you have just one replica, then use `maxUnavailable: 0` and `maxSurge: 1` along with the above config.

Comment: `kubectl rollout status deploy/my-deployment` will check latest deployment. Is it possible to select the just triggered deployment?

Comment: @Amrit Bera Getting the rollout status exit code doesn't seems to be a scaleable  solution because it will only give rollout successful when it will successfully deployed the latest deployment and removed the old deployment completely So its hard to get the correct timeout value for this. Any better solution you had in your mind ? I am facing this issue these days.